# imghdr fail to run from http stream

Tags: python, python-requests, imghdr

I use Python Requests to send a HTTP request, and in return I will get a stream of PNG from the server.

```
    r = self.a.send_request()
    self.assertEqual(
        'png',
        imghdr.what(None, r),
        "Couldn't get a PNG ImageGraph"
    )
```

This code results in:

imghdr TypeError: startswith first arg must be str

[According to Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html),

```
imghdr.what(filename[, h])

    Tests the image data contained in the file named by filename, and returns a string describing the image type. If optional h is provided, the filename is ignored and h is assumed to contain the byte stream to test.
```

Why do I still get the error even with byte stream?

---

**Edit 1**: Include the HTTP response from server.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Developer tools from server PNG response]

Comment: Can you show `self.a.send_request`?

Comment: My guess is that `r` is not `str` nor `None`.